# PL DOC source forge - 2 issues

Tags: function, stored-procedures, plsql, procedure, plsqldeveloper

I'm attempting to use [PLDOC source forge](http://pldoc.sourceforge.net/maven-site/) with my code to generate a neat page with comments of my liking.

I'm coming across 2 issues, any help would be appreciated:

1. I've been using tags (/**, */) to make comments and this works perfectly for functions, but does not appear in procedures. My Functions and procedures are independent and not in packages, and trying to add comments before the PROCEDURE declaration just gets deleted when saved.
2. If i try to use the recommended method of getting the data directly from teh database 
   (`call pldoc.bat -url jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL -user SCOTT -password TIGER -sql SYS_OWNER.DBMS_PIPE,SYS_OWNER.DBMS_OUTPUT`), it puts all the available functions and procedures under the user `SIS_OWNER` (`SIS_owner` is the only link available on the left hand side). I want to change this so that I can view all the methods in the list instead. Problem with procedures stated in 1 still exists with this method.

Please let me know if you have overcome this and any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about #2, but for #1 try placing the PLDOC comment just after the procedure declaration but before the first line of code, so immediately after the "IS".

Adding comments before the declaration will cause it to be ignored and not saved when compiled into the database. I have this issue with package level comments, and have solved it by adding my comments just after the package declaration. This should work with procedures as well.